# Question about "FOR EACH ROW" in SQL Triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

If I'm using a trigger to update one row, and it's only reading from the NEW row, is FOR EACH ROW even needed in the trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are never going to update more than 1 row with an update statement, then the for each row declaration in your trigger is optional.